# How to disable bootstrap button until input filled and button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve an odd request. I will also provide some back information as well. First and foremost the problem.

I want to disable a button until fields are filled and another button is clicked. I want a user to input data into the form and then click "save" to parse the data. The reason I have to do this is because I am communicating with a robot and it requires this to happen. I basically need to send 2 links to the robot in order for it to work. With that being said, I have one link onchange and one on a button. I tried onblur to avoid the save link but the time that it happened was too quick for the robot to process.

Here is the code I have...

```
<div class="form">
    <form id="pnform" name="pnform" language=javascript>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-lg" id="pname" placeholder="Enter Part Name" onchange="return pname_onchange()"  style="width:375px; height:50px">
    </form>
    <!--Parse Data To Robot On Form Change-->
    <script>
        function pname_onchange() {
            str = '/KCLDO/set%20var%20[hmi]Part_Name=' + "'" + document.pnform.pname.value + "'"   ;
            //alert(str);
            window.location.href = str  ;
        }
        function parseData() {
            str = '/KARELCMD/HMI';
            //alert(str);
            window.location.href = str;
        }
    </script>
    <!--End Parse-->
</div>
<br />
<a href="/KARELCMD/HMI">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg pt-4 pb-4 pr-5 pl-5 mb-3 mr-2">
        <h1>Save</h1>
    </button>
</a>
<a href="/fr/p_type.htm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg pt-4 pb-4 pr-2 pl-2 mb-3 ml-2">
        <h1>Continue</h1>
    </button>
</a>
```

Can anyone offer advice on this? I want the "Continue" button to be disabled until the user fills the form in and hits the save button.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an ID to your Continue button, and set the `disabled` attribute to begin with:

```
<a href="/fr/p_type.htm"><button id="continue" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg pt-4 pb-4 pr-2 pl-2 mb-3 ml-2" disabled><h1>Continue</h1></button></a>
```

Then add an event listener to your Save button:

```
 <a href="/KARELCMD/HMI" onclick="continueButton()"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg pt-4 pb-4 pr-5 pl-5 mb-3 mr-2"><h1>Save</h1></button></a>
```

Then make this function:

```
function continueButton() {
    if (document.getElementById("pname").value != "") {
        document.getElementById("continue").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```

And it should now work!

Hopefully this helps!